# Form Submit and pass attribute page-id data to Controller

Tags: php, ajax, forms

```
 <li><a href="" page-id="8" class="selectedMenu">
    <form method="post" action="newPage">
        <input type="text" page-id="8">
        <input type="submit" value="SETTINGS">
    </form>
</a></li>
```

This belong to the navigation bar. What i'm trying to do is when the user clicked a menu it will submit the form and I will get the page-id attribute and use it in my controller.
I tried using ajax but since it goes to other page it fails and this is what my superior said that I should use.

Comment: don't you want <input type="text" name="page-id" value="8" /> ?

Comment: If you want to do it with ajax can you post the ajax you tried so we can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use $_POST['inputname'] then store it in a variable.
But a form in a nav. That is not advisable. Try another work around for your project.